# How to show array of objects in Angular 2 inside a template

Tags: angular, ngfor

I can't show an array of objects inside a template. This is part of my code:

Component.ts

```
export class UpcomingMoviesComponent implements OnInit {
    movies: Movie[];
}
getUpcomingMovies() {
    this.moviesRes = res.results; 
    let i = 0;
    for (let item in this.moviesRes) {
        for (let subItem in this.moviesRes[item]) {
            this.movies.push(new Movie());
            this.movies[i].id = this.moviesRes[item]["id"];
            i++;
        }
     }
});
```

Template.html (I have tried several things but none of them worked)

```
<div *ngFor="let movie of this.movies">
   {{movie.id}}
   {{movie[0].id}}
</div>
```

If I use the following

```
{{this.movies | json}}
```

I get this:

```
[
  {
    "id":346672
  }
]
```

Could you help me to show this object inside a template. thanks

Comment: For one thing `getUpcomingMovies` doesn't appear to be in the class...

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use `this` in templates. Compiler resolves the context, so you can just write:

```
<div *ngFor="let movie of movies">
```